# Customize tree-grid-directive template

Tags: angularjs

Please I need help, 
I'm using this tree-grid-directive https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive, and I want to cutomize the template but I don't know where to do so.
Once I added `template-url="pathtotemplate"` to `<tree-grid></tree-grid>` the tree-grid disappeared:
html file :

```
<tree-grid tree-data="tree_data" tree-control="my_tree" col-defs="col_defs" 
            expand-on="expanding_property" on-select="my_tree_handler(branch)" on-click="my_tree_handler_s(branch)" 
             expand-level="2" template-url="temp/tree-grid-template.html"
  icon-leaf= "glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></tree-grid>
```

template htmlfile (i haven't changed anything):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree-grid-template.html">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped tree-grid">
            <thead class="text-primary">
                <tr>
                    <th>{{expandOn}}</th>
                    <th ng-repeat="col in colDefs">{{col.displayName || col.field}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" 
ng-class="'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" 
class="tree-grid-row">
                    <td class="text-primary"><a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
<i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" 
class="indented tree-icon"></i></a>
<span class="indented tree-label">{{row.branch[expandOn]}}</span></td>
                    <td ng-repeat="col in colDefs">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

I've also tried (**in tree-grid-directive.js file**) to change every url to the one with my template but nothing change, it just shows me the tree-grid with no changes.

Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: I think there is no need to add ``script`` tag in template file and also have you included ``Bootstrap`` files as suggested  in ``tree-grid-directive`` ??

Comment: It worked, how do I include Bootstrap files in tree-grid-directive ?

Comment: Only bootstrap css file is required .  Include that in in file where you have included angular.js file. may be index.html   Did it worked after removing ``script`` tag ??.

Comment: And if you want use your own template then no need to include bootstrap css file too. You can have your own CSS file .

Comment: yes, I already have it included. Yes it worked perfectly just have to customize the template. thank you so much